# C++/CLI: Loop through non-continuous enum

Tags: enums, c++-cli

I'm writing a `C++/CLI` wrapper around a C# library. The libary exposes an enum with non-continuous numeric values (which is something beyond my control, and I would never, never, add this myself, but it needs to be maintained for backwards compatibility)

```
enum MyCSEnum
{
    Value1 = 1,
    Value2 = 2,
    Value3 = 3,
    Value4 = 5,
    Value5 = 7,
    Value6 = 10,
    Value7 = 13
};
```

Is there a way to loop over this enum in `c++/clr`? I can't loop through it numerically, as the underlying values are non-continuous. I know that in `C#` a range-based loop is possible, but how would this be done in `C++/CLI`

Comment: If the enum will not be changed, you can write 'for (auto i : {MyEnum::Value1, MyEnum::Value2, ... MyEnum::Value7}) {}'.

Comment: @UriRaz: I would create function `constexpr std::array<MyEnum, N> AllMyEnum()` though.

Comment: *"I would never, never"* -> There's no no-no against non-continuous enum values in C++.  Anyway: You could turn it into an enum class and define an `operator++`.   The real issue here is that by having a range loop for enums in C#, people will use them for non-contiguous values that will commonly be looped through, whereas in C++ you would not use an enum for something like that (meaning, something that will commonly be naively looped through).  Notice when enum classes were introduced, they suspiciously did not include automagical iteration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Enum::GetValues`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.getvalues) will return an array containing all the valid enum values. Call that method, and iterate over the result.

Obviously, this requires that the enum in question be a managed enum, not an unmanaged C++ enum. The example enum you showed appears to be an unmanaged enum, but if this is a wrapper of a C# library, then there's probably a managed version of that enum around that you can use.

You could also use `Enum::GetValues` as a building block to produce a collection of unmanaged enum values within the library, which you can then use to iterate over the unmanaged enum.

Comment: ``System::Array^ enumValues = System::Enum::GetValues(MyEnum::typeid); `` does seem to allow me to get an array of values. Hoever, these seem to be ``Object^``. How can I use these as enums?

Comment: A simple cast to `MyEnum` will do the trick. The array is typed as `Object^`, but the objects are of the proper enum type under the hood.

Comment: It works, I can even convert between the C# enum and C++ enum via an implicit conversion: ``System::Array^ enumValues = System::Enum::GetValues(MyCSEnum::typeid);

   for each(MyCSEnum enumValue in enumValues)
   {
    MyCPPEnum cppEnumValue = MyCppEnum(enumValue)
   }``

Answer (score 0):

No.

C++/CLI is an extension to C++, and C++ has no reflection. Reflection would be required for this.

You'll have to maintain an array of "valid" values, and/or use some macro tricks.

Comment: could you provide more info regarding `some macro tricks`?